# Shopping cart (php)

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am currently working on a shopping cart project rn for a certain subject. This is how I implement my shoppong cart

1. Products are read from an xml file (I don't have much of an idea on how to use sql yet so...) w/ the following details: prodID, prodName, prodDesc, prodPrice, and prodStock
2. Every time the user adds items to their cart, the items' respective stocks are updated on the xml file.

Other things: I'm using a session variable, $_SESSION['items'], which is the cart of the user. This session variable is an array of objects, Product, which contains the following: prodID, prodName, prodPrice, prodQTY(the number the user wants). I don't implement the login system here since it might be annoying for the users, IMO.

When the user buys the products he added into the cart, there is no problem. However, whenever the user abandons the cart (via browser close or whatnot), the stocks of said items do not go back to their original states. Is there any way for me to keep track the case of a cart abandoment? Or is there something about my implementation I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to not change stock levels until the user has been through the checkout process.

Until they have confirmed the purchase neither the merchant nor the customer has entered into a contract and there for stock levels should not change.

Comment: But irl, when you get an item from an item shelf and let's say that is the last of that item in that item shelf, other shoppers can't get that item from you anymore (unless you abandon it or... the other shoppers get it from you by force). My point here is that, once an item is added from the cart, the stock in the shelf should be deducted and if the user decides to abandon the cart or remove an item from the cart, the items in the cart would return to their respective shelves. (If the user does not commit, then rollback).

Comment: True. However, from a stock taking perspective, the store would not remove it from their inventory until it passed through checkout. A warning to customers that there are only a few left in stock should suffice. Then, they are in a race scenario.

Comment: If that were the case, then here's the implementation I think you want me to have: 1. The user adds an item to the cart (let's say 40 of something). 2. The user proceeds to checkout 3.The stock is updated 4.In the event of another user checks out more than the stock, a prompt will appear to that user

Comment: Yes, basically. To my mind, reducing available stock when someone has only shown an interest is good for the one customer who showed interest but bad for everybody else. It's bad for you because if they do not buy but someone else would have, you lose a sale, it's bad for other customers because they may miss out on the purchase. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.